# d3 skips first index in an array when appending circles

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, d3.js

I'm new to using D3 and I'm trying to evenly place circles around another circle by dividing into n pieces. The problem is that it does not draw the first circle even though coords[0] exists. Instead it places starts at coords[1] and continues. Any reason why this is and how to fix it?

main.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>A Circle</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.16.1/math.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="circle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

circle.js

```
    var w = 500;
    var h = 500;
    var n = 10;
    var r = h/2-20;
    var coords = [];

    for (var i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        var p_i = {};
        p_i.x = w/2+r*math.cos((2*math.pi/n)*i);
        p_i.y = h/2-r*math.sin((2*math.pi/n)*i);
        coords.push(p_i);
    }


    var svg = d3.select('body') //SVG Canvas
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', w)
        .attr('height', h);

    var circle = svg.append('circle') //Draw Big Circle
        .attr('cx', w/2)
        .attr('cy', h/2)
        .attr('r', r)
        .attr('fill', 'teal')
        .attr('stroke', 'black')
        .attr('stroke-width', w/100);

    var center = svg.append('circle') //Construct Center
        .attr('cx', w/2)
        .attr('cy', h/2)
        .attr('r', r/50)
        .attr('fill', 'red')
        .attr('stroke', 'black')
        .attr('stroke-width', w/100);

    var approx_pts = svg.selectAll('circle')
        .data(coords, function(d)
              {
                  return this.id;
              })
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', function(d)
              {
                  return d.x;
              })
        .attr('cy', function(d)
              {
                  return d.y;
              })
        .attr('r', w/100)
        .attr('fill', 'black');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have circles in the SVG when you do this:

```
var approx_pts = svg.selectAll('circle')
```

Therefore, your "enter" selection has less elements than your data array.

Solution: just use `selectAll(null)`:

```
var approx_pts = svg.selectAll(null)
```

That way you can be sure that your enter selection has all the elements in your data array. Of course, this approach avoids creating an "update" and "exit" selections in the future.

If you do plan to use an "update" and "exit" selections, you can select by class:

```
var approx_pts = svg.selectAll(".myCircles")
```

Don't forget to set that class when you append those circles in the enter selection, of course.

Comment: This is a nice simple answer but the issue is that I do plan to update the graphic via a slider. Is there any way to solve this issue in such a way I may update the image?

Comment: @1028 Check my edit at the end of the answer. The easiest way to do this is using an exclusive class for those circles.